# jq - extract additional JSON object into new array

Tags: json, jq

I have some JSON. It looks like this:

```
{
"Volumes": [
    {
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "VolumeId": "vol-11111111",
                "State": "attached",
                "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                "Device": "/dev/sdz"
            }
        ],
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "volume1",
                "Key": "Name"
            },
            {
                "Value": "00:00",
                "Key": "Start"
            },
            {
                "Value": "00:20",
                "Key": "Finish"
            },
            {
                "Value": "2",
                "Key": "Period"
            }
        ],
        "VolumeId": "vol-11111111"
    },
    {
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "VolumeId": "vol-22222222",
                "State": "attached",
                "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                "Device": "/dev/sdz"
            }
        ],
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "volume2",
                "Key": "Name"
            },
            {
                "Value": "00:00",
                "Key": "Start"
            },
            {
                "Value": "00:20",
                "Key": "Finish"
            },
            {
                "Value": "2",
                "Key": "Period"
            }
        ],
        "VolumeId": "vol-22222222"
    },
    {
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "VolumeId": "vol-333333333",
                "State": "attached",
                "DeleteOnTermination": false,
                "Device": "/dev/sdz"
            }
        ],
        "Tags": [
            {
                "Value": "volume3",
                "Key": "Name"
            },
            {
                "Value": "00:00",
                "Key": "Start"
            },
            {
                "Value": "00:20",
                "Key": "Finish"
            },
            {
                "Value": "2",
                "Key": "Period"
            }
        ],
        "VolumeId": "vol-33333333"
    }
]
}
```

Using jq, I am able to extract the following information:

VolumeId,Finish,Start,Period

using the jq command

```
cat json | jq -r '[.Volumes[]|({VolumeId}+(.Tags|from_entries))|{VolumeId,Finish,Start,Period}]'

[
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-11111111",
    "Finish": "00:20",
    "Start": "00:00",
    "Period": "2"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-22222222",
    "Finish": "00:20",
    "Start": "00:00",
    "Period": "2"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-33333333",
    "Finish": "00:20",
    "Start": "00:00",
    "Period": "2"
  }
]
```

---

All this works fine. However I have the need to additional extract .Attachments.Device. I am looking for output for each array similar to:

```
 [
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-11111111",
    "Finish": "00:20",
    "Start": "00:00",
    "Period": "2",
    "DeviceId": "/dev/sdz"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-22222222",
    "Finish": "00:20",
    "Start": "00:00",
    "Period": "2",
    "DeviceId": "/dev/sdz"
  },
  {
    "VolumeId": "vol-33333333",
    "Finish": "00:20",
    "Start": "00:00",
    "Period": "2",
    "DeviceId": "/dev/sdz"
  }
]
```

However I can't figure out how to do this without getting an error. The most logical approach for me would be to do something like:

```
cat json | jq -r '[.Volumes[]|({VolumeId}+(.Attachments|from_entries)+(.Tags|from_entries))|{VolumeId,Finish,Start,Period,DeviceId}]'
```

However I get the error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:91): Cannot use null (null) as object key
```

Any help figuring out what I am not doing correct and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Please fix the JSON.  `"Attachments": "Attachments":` is incorrect.

Comment: @peak: apologies; fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the problem is that you're using `from_entries` on the `Attachments` array when it wouldn't work.  `from_entries` takes an array of key/value pair objects to create an object with those values.  However, you don't have key/value pairs, but objects.  If you're just trying to combine them, you should use `add`.

Also, there is no property named `DeviceId`, it's `Device`.  If you want to select the `Device` property and get it as `DeviceId`, you need to provide the correct name.

```
.Volumes | map(
    ({ VolumeId } + (.Attachments | add) + (.Tags | from_entries))
      | { VolumeId, Finish, Start, Period, DeviceId: .Device }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are right; it's 'Device' and not 'DeviceId'. Unfortunately though this is not the root cause of the issue. It appears to be with `+(.Attachments|from_entries)` that causes the error, which is needed for me to pull .Attachments[]. `+(.Tags|from_entries)` works fine

Comment: Ah, right. Now it's clear what the problem is.  I'll update.